# Missing image from my answer

Tags: support

Look here:
[What is the difference between 'log' and 'symlog'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305865/what-is-the-difference-between-log-and-symlog)

One of the images (http://a.imageshack.us/img821/9840/matplotlibxscalesymlog.png) is now returning 404 Not Found. It is worth noting that the answer has not been changed at all, so somehow the image hosting service deleted or lost the image. Can someone please take a look?

(BTW, not sure if I should have marked this as `bug` or `support`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

This is PRECISELY why the stackexchange imagehost needs to be used as opposed to anything else - to avoid things like this. Use the built in image importer. Its your friend.

[image]

You can use that to import in images you have already uploaded (I often quick upload screenshots to imgur, then pop em in there) or upload directly. stackexchange imgur links *never* break, so you can be assured your images will be there tommorrow.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I didn't notice I was using imageshack. I guess I posted that answer before StackExchange had its own image hosting. I'll fix it later.