# Fixing images - What to do when the question is otherwise correct, but has potentially breakable images

Tags: discussion

I attempted to [edit this question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1558290) to shift all the images into imgur. [One link is already broken](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168278/missing-image-from-my-answer/168280#168280) and there's a very real chance the rest will break. The rest of the question seems fine. However, well, there appears to be a bit of a conflict, as I got 3 rejects and two accepts - it was pretty much russian roulette. I know on some of the trilogy sites, fixing images was welcome, and I was attempting to be a good citizen.

Does fixing images so they don't break count as a substantiative edit? I don't really care about the rep, I just wanted to keep more images for breaking, so I'm fine with someone with edit rights doing it too. I'd just like to know what's the best way of handling such things

Comment: I know Journeyman Geek well on SU and he has always contributed helpful answers and edits.  This edit would have been approved on Super User. (SU ♦ here)

Comment: What are "trilogy sites"?

Comment: Reviewers not looking at the markdown might not notice the difference. And your edit message (*"replaced all but the b0rken image with stack.imgur links. FOR THE GREATER GLORY OF GRUMPYCAT"*) doesn't read all that serious either. Not saying that's what caused it (and I would surely have accepted it) but it might have contributed.

Comment: @ruda.almeida Stack Overflow, Super User and Server Fault.

Comment: @Bart: I admit, bit of an inside joke, and one that probably would have made more sense with the MSO question I linked. Not everyone posts serious edit reasons, and the main part of it covered what I did. I probably should have linked the MSO question instead.

Comment: Note: I have now edited the images I could edit. The broken one is still a problem.

Comment: I think @Bart hit the nail on the head. I was thinking exactly the same when I saw this ridiculously stupid edit message.

Comment: I tend to assume no one reads the edit message. I'll keep it in mind in the future, should this happen again.